# mce Hardware error while saving disk image with Clonezilla

Tags: disk-image, clonezilla, imaging

I was saving an image with **Clonezilla alternative stable - 20170905-zesty**, option **To Ram**, of my new hp spectre x360 with a 256GB nvme disk. I had chosen to "check the saved image", and to poweroff when done. The **mce hardware errors** in the pictures happened while saving 2 partitions:

[mce Hardware error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BmaY.jpg); [mce Hardware error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hwJRQ.jpg)

Nonetheless the process went on and, when done, I wasn't able to read any message since the pc turned off immediatly. Does those two errors affect the integrity of my image? Will I be able to restore the disk image in this regard?

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine, as long as the clone zilla said clone sucsesfully, or you can just try to restore the image on another disk and try it, mce mean something wrong with the machine... i have same isue before, i  install windows 10 on emmc 32gb, when save the image it say mce error, i try to reformat the emmc then restore that image, everything works fine